# What does this icon next to the player mean?

Tags: nba2k12

The star means all star, basket means can dunk, the three means that they have a good three pointer.  But what does this icon mean?

[image]

Comment: It means you're the victim of sponsored, in-game advertisements.  :-(

Comment: It means take a drink.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Gatorade symbol indicates that a player is tiring and needs to be substituted. As is the case with most sports games, the manual mentions nothing about this at all; the only hint I found about it was on [the hoopsgaming forum](http://hoopsgaming.com/archive/index.php/t-6518.html).

Comment: Refreshment levels critical, enter Gatorade™ product code to continue